# How to call a .Net COM+ object from C++ functions library?

Tags: c#, c++, api, com+

I've not found some example that really works. I need to create an interaction system for MetaTrader. It's better to use modern technologies like WCF or somehting else using C#, but MetaTrader doesn't support COM or just OOP at all. So I need some gateway component that must be functions library with non-object interface. Surely, it requires usage of C++. But I'm not succeeded to find over the Web some example how to call from a C++ functions library a C# COM+ DLL. All the examples I could find use component C++ assemblies that are not supported by MetaTrader. So, I can't use namespace, etc. in C++. I wrote a COM+ server application that is easy to call from C# by the following lines

```
object c2 = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Imutome.COMPlusCache.Cache"));
c2.GetType().InvokeMember("OnTransfer", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, c2, null);
```

But when I'm trying to write in C++ something like this

```
CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("Imutome.COMPlusCache.Cache"), &rclsid);
HRESULT hres = CoCreateInstance(rclsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IDispatch, (void **)&ppv);
```

I get just zeros in ppv and "0x80040154 Class not registered" in hres. I'm not sure what flags or what interface are required but I get the same error whatever I try. Although in C# everything works. Tell me please what do I need to change to make C++ succesfully create a COM+ object instance.

Comment: What happens if you pass CLSCTX_ALL? Also does `CLSIDFromProgID()` actually retrieve the right class id?

Comment: Have you initialized COM in the C++ thread? What about narrowing down the problem by trying to create some other more basic COM object using the same code (but a different ProgId, obviously).

Comment: (BTW depending on how you registered the C# assembly, it may need to be in the same directory as the running app)

Comment: @mackenir: He would have got another error code if he hadn't initialized COM.

Comment: CLSCTX_ALL doesn't help also. Of course, I've used CoInitialize before. The C# assembly is registered using ComponentService GUI. May be IID_IDispatch is really incorrect but I don't know what can I replace it with. ComponentService displays IManagedObject and other interfaces of ServicedComponent and one my inteface ICache.

Comment: By the way, here's ComponentService screenshot [image](http://s54.radikal.ru/i145/1103/54/3a8c18ecb5de.gif)

Comment: I guess you could use Process Monitor to try diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is in the way you register your component.
You shoud use:

> regasm your_component_name.dll /tlb
>   /codebase

OR

> regasm your_component_name.dll /tlb

AND put your component library to GAC or your executable location.
Hope this helps.
ComponentService GUI is not the same.

Comment: The problem is solved. The reason was really very simple. It was that the example from the Web I've used for the base had `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]`
So, the strong name didn't match the assembly version. I had just to replace the asteric.